# Adding Atex Markdown Headers in Vim

Tags: filetype-markdown

Is there a way to make it so that

```
This is a header
=<tab>
```

converts into

```
This is a header
================
```

in all files who filetype is markdown?

Answer (score 2):

Likely it can be done with <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>, but another approach is:

1. type your header, then <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> (copy the whole line in Visual mode)
2. <kbd>p</kbd>aste
3. <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> (move down, select whole line, replace it with `=`.

Then You can create a macro or an `imap` or `nmap` for it.

Another approach is (after typing your header and getting back to normal mode is: `:t.|s/./=/g` (ex mode copy line bellow and replace every character on it with `=`.

Comment: `yy` is enough to copy the line

Comment: Is there away to somehow attach `:t.|s/./=/g` or your other method to the `=<tab>` action?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
This is a header
=
```

On the line with `=` type:

```
<ESC>Vly5p
```

1. `V` puts vim into visual mode.
2. `l` (letter l) moves the cursor to the left.
3. `y` copies the `=`.
4. `5` is the number of `=`s you want.
5. `p` inserts the `=`s.